# Fix or Start Over (MS Access Database)?

Tags: ms-access

I have sort of agreed to help out a small local community non-profit org with a database that was created for them many years ago.  The original developer, along with his original uncompiled files are long gone, the current file has many problems, but since it is a .mde file I can't pull it apart to see how it all works.  I do have access to the Tables and I can see what the Reports look like (just not how and where they get the data).

My feeling is that it might just be easier (and quicker!) to create a new version using what I can see in the original database as the basis for the new one.  This way whatever problems they are experiencing will be resolved and all of the legacy stuff they no longer need/use will be removed.  Plus, they will have a version that can be modified in the future even if I'm not around.

If you've had to deal with a similar situation how did you go about deciding which direction to head in?  In other words, what are the typical considerations/traps I need to know about before taking on this adventure (other than it taking way more time and effort than I think it will)?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be able to import objects to a new db but no VBA code will be recovered. Review http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/createmdbfrommde.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first determine if big or minor changes are needed now or to be expected in the near future. If not, I'd try to find a way to keep the system alive.

On the other hand, you already provided some good arguments for setting up a new system that I agree with. I would add to that that is much more satisfying to do this. Almost always you wish you started from greenfield if you try to alter an old legacy system.

Point to considder, is that you might need to train the existing users to work with the new system.

Good luck!